# Is it possible to take screenshot of a perticular item in Recyclerview and share it via intent?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, share, screenshot, android-bitmap

I am using Recyclerview to display my feeds in my Android app. For each feed I have a share option. I was hoping is there any way that I can take the snapshot of that particular feed and share it via Intent-Chooser.

PS: I have searched for answers and found that we can take a bitmap of the screen shot, save it into internal/external Storage and share it via Uri. But Can it be done without saving the snapshot into memory? Just share and forget..

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list item view into bitmap and then share that image over intent.

Use this method to convert view to Bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: what view should I pass as the argument?
Should I pass the ItemView of Recycler view?